# python-rq worker not reading jobs in queue

Tags: python, python-rq

I'm facing a basic issue while setting up python-rq - the `rqworker` doesn't seem to recognize jobs that are pushed to the queue it's listening on.

Everything is run inside `virtualenv`
I have the following code:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from rq.registry import FinishedJobRegistry
from videogen import videogen
import time

redis_conn = Redis(port=5001)
videoq = Queue('medium', connection=redis_conn)
fin_registry = FinishedJobRegistry(connection=redis_conn, name='medium')

jobid = 1024
job = videoq.enqueue(videogen, jobid)

while not job.is_finished:
    time.sleep(2)
    print job.result
```

Here `videogen` is a simple function which immediately returns the integer parameter it receives.

On running `rqworker medium` and starting the app, there is no result printed. There are NO extra traces at rqworker other than this:

```
14:41:29 RQ worker started, version 0.5.0
14:41:29 
14:41:29 *** Listening on medium...
```

The redis instance is accessible from the same shell where I run rqworker, as even shows the updated keys:

```
127.0.0.1:5001> keys *
1) "rq:queues"
2) "rq:queue:medium"
3) "rq:job:9a46f9c5-03e1-4b08-946b-61ad2c3815b1"
```

So what is possibly missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Silly error - had to supply redis connection url to rqworker
`rqworker --url redis://localhost:5001 medium`

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that this can also happen if you run your RQ workers on Windows, which is not supported by the workers. From the [documentation](https://python-rq.org/docs/#limitations):

> RQ workers will only run on systems that implement `fork()`. Most
> notably, this means it is not possible to run the workers on Windows
> without using the Windows Subsystem for Linux and running in a bash
> shell.